# Making simple calculator in c by while and if statement

Tags: c

First I'm new to c .
I wanted to make a small calculator which can do simple tasks. But  this always shows  only show the  ans is 0.0000. . What should I require here?

```
 char op;
  int n1;
  int n2;
  float ans;
  int n;


while(op!='q'){
  scanf("%c",&op);
  if (op=='a'||op=='s'||op=='m'||op=='d'){

  printf("Enter first number\n");
  scanf("%d",&n1);
  printf("Enter secound number\n");
  scanf("%d",&n2);

  if (op=='a'){ans=n1+n2;}
  else if(op=='s'){ans=n1-n2;}
  else if(op=='m'){ans=n1*n2;}
  else if(op=='d'){ans=n1/n2;}

  }
  else if(op=='p'||op=='r'||op=='n'||op=='c'){

    printf("Enter   number\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);


  if (op=='p'){ans=n^2;}
  else if(op=='r'){ans=n^(1/2);}
  else if(op=='n'){ans=sin(n);}
  else if(op=='c'){ans=cos(n);}

  }

printf("%f\n",&ans);

}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Spamming irrelevant tags gives you a closed question, not faster answer.

Comment: Do not spam tags

Comment: `^` refers to bitwise XOR, not exponentiation. `n^(1/2)` will always be `n^0`, which will in turn always be `n`.

Comment: `printf("%f\n",&ans);` invokes *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type. You should remove the extra `&` and use `printf("%f\n",ans);`.

Comment: @NathanPierson `n^(1/2)` will always be `n`, not necessary `0`.

Comment: `op!='q'` with uninitialized `op` also invokes *undefined behavior* unless `op` is a global (or static) variable.

Comment: One more thing: For obsure reasons, you're going to need to change `scanf("%c", &op);` to `scanf(" %c", &op);`.

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems:

**Wrong argument**

`printf("%f\n",&ans);` attempts to print an address as a floating point.

This is *undefined behavior* (UB).

---

Instead, enable all warnings to catch simple issues like this.

Use an exponential format for more informative output.

```
// printf("%f\n",&ans);
printf("%g\n", ans);
//  or 
printf("%e\n", ans);
```

**Wrong operation**

`n^2` is `n` exclusive-or'd with 2.  OP likely wants `n*n` to square a value.

**<kbd>Enter</kbd> (`'\n'`) is a character too**

OP certainly does not want to read `'\n'` as an `op`.  Include a space to consume leading white-spaces like `'\n'`.

```
// scanf("%c",&op);
scanf(" %c",&op); // space added
```

**Integer division**

`1/2` is 0.  Use `0.5` or `1.0/2.0`.

**Use `double`**

Save `float` for special cases.

```
// float ans;
double ans;

// if (op=='p'){ans=n^2;}
if (op=='p') { ans = 1.0 * n * n; }  // Use FP multiplication
// else if(op=='r'){ans=n^(1/2);}
else if(op=='r') { ans = sqrt(n); }

else if(op=='n'){ans=sin(n);}  // Note that sin, cos are double functions
else if(op=='c'){ans=cos(n);}
```

**Uninitialized `op`**

Code tests `op` before assigning it. [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72967215/making-simple-calculator-in-c-by-while-and-if-statement/72967480#comment128877296_72967215)

```
// char op;
char op = 0;
while(op!='q'){
```